# Node, Mongodb count array in API and reset / start again using cron job

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, cron, request

I’m creating a rota where everyday the user changes. I have a database with each row is a different member of staff.

I need count how many rows are in the database and then count them to display a different user each day. When the array gets the end, it needs to go back to the start for example the array is 0 to 4 when it gets to 4 the next one will need to be 0 and not 5.

The example below I have changed the cron job to every 1min for testing.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), 
Staff = mongoose.model('staffmembers'); 
var cron = require('node-cron');

var next = cron.schedule('*/1 * * * MON-FRI', function() {

    Staff.find({}, (err,results) => {

        var i = results.length++;
        console.log(results[i%results.length].name)

    })


 });

 next.start();
```

When I run the code below

```
console.log(results[1].name)
```

I get the name back I want to do this with the count.

Comment: too many confusions.. 
1) what is update the name displayed
2) what is count from 0 to the value of the array.
3) what is reset.
please clarify the problem you are facing properly with minimum viewable code. Thanks

Comment: @SaikatHajra sorry about that I have now updated the question.

Comment: `But also go back to the start when it hits the end` can you please clarify this sentence @Thomas

Comment: @SaikatHajra also updated